# Do WebApi 2 and MVC 5 user different routing attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-routing, asp.net-web-api2

Reading through [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) blog post on attribute routing in ASP.NET MVC 5 and [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) one on attribute routing in Web Api 2, it looks like there are two sets of routing attributes, one in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace and the other in `System.Web.Http`.

1. Is that right and does anyone have any idea (links) as to why it was designed this way?
2. Should one be used over the other or are they supposed to live side by side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, these route attributes are intentionally different since Web API and MVC have distinct (but similar) routing systems
2. Use the MVC RouteAttribute on MVC controllers/actions. Use the Web API RouteATtribute (System.Web.Http) on Web API controllers/actions. If you use one that doesn't match, it likely just won't work.

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference for them having different routing systems?

Comment: Well, I'm on the product team and have worked on both routing systems; does that count? :) Also, see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: That does indeed count, I guess I was also hoping for more of an explanation of why, but the part at the top of the article you linked to about using HTTP method for routing sort of addresses that.