# 2 RouteAttribute in different namespaces?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What's the difference of the following 2 RouteAttributes?

- System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute
- System.Web.MVC.RouteAttribute

### Update 1

I just found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936647/do-webapi-2-and-mvc-5-user-different-routing-attributes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web API borrowed some ideas from ASP.NET MVC and duplicated some type names from ASP.NET MVC namespaces. But Web API is totally different beast from ASP.NET MVC.